# requestFileSystem not firing any callbacks on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using PhoneGap build from Adobe. I am trying to write to iOS native file storage.

My config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<gap:platform name="ios" />
```

Index.html contains

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

My js

```
window.onerror = function(error) { console.log(error); };
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('Here we go');
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log('Ready');
}

function onFileSystemFail(e) {
    console.log('Fail');
}
```

Confirmed plugins are loading:

[image]

My console output is:

> here we go

But I get nothing else, no fail or success messages so I'm totally in the dark about whether it was successful or not.

Comment: Does it happen every time or only occasionally, Im getting the same issue on android but it seems to happen 2 out of 3 times. The 3rd time it works just fine

Comment: Having exact same issues.  Requestfilesystem will sometimes begin immediately, sometimes it takes 2-3 tries.

Comment: I also have the same issue