# Cordova 3.5 requestFileSystem occasionally failes to resolve Android 4.2.2

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-3

Using Cordova 3.5.0, Android 4.2.2 and the following plugins:

- org.apache.cordova.file 1.1.0
- org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.3
- org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.8
- com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics 0.5.0

I am only able to get the call to requestFileSystem to resolve once out of every 3 loads of the app. When it loads everything works fine. But when it doesnt the app just hangs waiting forever.

It looks like this may not be only related to Android as there are some other similar questions for iOS:

[requestFileSystem not firing any callbacks on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814647/requestfilesystem-not-firing-any-callbacks-on-ios)

[requestFileSystem never returns Cordova 3.4 on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582850/requestfilesystem-never-returns-cordova-3-4-on-ios)

Im not using the console plugin so the second questions possible solution doesnt help. Does anyone know why the function is hanging and not returning success/fail?

Comment: If you just drop down to the file plugin only, does the behavior continue?

Comment: It looks like it may be a problem with the google analytics plugin, without that plugin added back in I havent had the error where it fails to resolve.